# Examples of (non-)disjoint (in)dependent events

Tags: probability

I need examples of:

1. Disjoint but independent events

My guess: In an experiment where a coin is tossed twice in a row, define events E={get head} and F={get tail}. E and F are disjoint and independent.

2. Non-disjoint but independent events

My guess: In an experiment where a 6-faced dice is rolled, define events E={get odd number} and F={roll 3}. E and F are non-disjoint and independent.

3. Disjoint but dependent events

My guess: In an experiment where you draw balls from a bag containing 5 red balls and 3 green balls without replacement, define E={draw red ball} and F={draw green ball}. E and F are disjoint and dependent.

4. Non-disjoint but dependent events

My guess: Same experiment as (3) but with E={draw red ball} and F={draw red ball}. E and F are non-disjoint and dependent.

Am I right?

Comment: No.  "Disjoint" events are mutually exclusive, so they can not occur together.  Barring degenerate cases, this means they can't be independent.  Note that the events in your first case are not clearly defined.  As you are tossing the coin twice, which toss(es) do $E,F$ refer to?

Comment: Nor is "rolling a $3$" independent from "rolling an odd number".

Comment: @lulu So there is no such thing as disjoint (in)dependent events? If so, how would you correctly classify the properties of events I described in (1) and (3)?

Comment: @lulu why rolling 3 is dependent on rolling an odd number?

Comment: How are you defining "independent"?  Whatever definition you are using, apply it to the dice example.

Comment: Note:  to be technical, most people define independence via $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$.  That makes a lot of sense, but it allows for "degenerate" cases in which one or both of the events has probability $0$.  Thus, if you are choosing a real number in $[0,1]$ uniformly the events "you get $\frac 12$" and "you get $\frac 13$" are independent, since both events, and their intersection, have probability $0$.  That would be an example of two disjoint, independent events.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I use that definition.

Comment: Ok, so then apply it to the dice case.  Note that if $A$ is the event "you got a $3$" and $B$ is the event "you got an odd number", then $A\cap B=A$.

Comment: @lulu I see, this is the example of a non-disjoint and dependent event then? You said that disjoint but dependent events are impossible, then do you have any examples of non-disjoint but independent events?

Comment: No ..I said that disjoint and independent  is not possible, barring degenerate cases. Typically, all disjoint events are dependent (knowing that one occurred tells you that the other didn't occur).